# Order category by position

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, category-products, sorting

I seem to be having a problem with the sorting position within categories as it is not displaying properly. I have my "Product Listing Sort By" set to 'best value'.

Within a single category i have products set by position, '1, 2, 3, 4, etc..', Yet on the frontend they don't want to be displayed in this order?

Can't seem to get the sorting right, any suggestions?

I am using Magento CE 1.9.2.4

Comment: Have you tried changing the setting for `System->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog->Frontend->Product Listing Sort by` to something else?  Also, it would be worth checking for values at Website\Store View levels for both the default value and the value set on the category itself.

Comment: I am having the same issue...it doesn't change the default sorting in the categories, nor does it reflect on the front end.